# Azure Data Factory, Mongo DB Connectionstring has special character

Tags: mongodb, azure-data-factory

I have to connect MongoDB in azure data factory, the password of the mongoDB has  '@' sign in it, which seems to be causing some issue. is there any way to escape that character?

the connection string is some thing look alike given below,

```
mongodb://username:p@ssword@abc.company.com:1800/db_name
```

Comment: as per the document the '@' needs to be replaced with %40, but still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

I got the answer,

I have to use '%40' instead of '@'

so the connectionstring will go like this

mongodb://username:p%40ssword@abc.company.com:1800/db_name

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this tutorial: [Copy data from MongoDB using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb).

The MongoDB connection string format is look like this:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host[:port][/[database][?options]]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.